# How we took the line from $(1,3)$ to $(1,1)$ into account during integration?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

Here is one of the questions of a subject GRE exam:

> [image]

The solution said that the shaded area is bounded from above by the line $x+2$ and from below by the absolute value function this is why the answer is $A.$ My question is: How we took the line from $(1,3)$ to $(1,1)$ into account during integration? I see that the shaded region is also bounded by that line in addition to the line $x+2.$ Could anyone explain this to me, please?

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Line $x=-1$ and $x=1$ are included by default since those are the limits of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are integrating with respect to $x$, and the $x$-coordinate of all points on that line stays constant. Hence, it is included as one of the bounds of integration.

Answer (score 1):

The trapezoid area is trivially $3$ and the (A) integral gives $3$ too, but the function does not represent the trapezoid.

[image]